# Ubuntu/Tomcat Server UTF-8 encoding issue

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, encoding, utf-8

I have developing a web application using Java/Jsp running on an Ubuntu 14.04 LTS server with Tomcat 8, where the following UTF-8 encoding problem with the section sign § apperas.

Any form Input of the section sign **§** at the server side will is converted to **Â§** and I have no clue why.

Simple sysout:

```
Should Print [§] - [output]: Â§
Char: Â§ ASCII 167
```

The HTML/Client side is ok since a wireshark trace shows me the correct char § is delivered to the server. So the issues must be at the tomcat-server itself.

The following things are set already:

1. set JSP Encodings, HTML5 Encodings

```
&lt%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
    &ltmeta charset="utf-8" />
```

2. set Java Encodings

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse 
response)
    throws ServletException, IOException {
    // Set CharSet to UTF-8
    response.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
```

3. Serversettings

```
    locale -a 
        C
        C.UTF-8
        en_US.utf8
        POSIX
```

4. tomcat.conf Tomcat 8 settings

```
env JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.awt.headless=true -
    Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -
Djavax.servlet.request.encoding=UTF-8 -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8"
    env CATALINA_OPTS="-Xms512M -Xmx1024M -server -XX:+UseParallelGC -
Dfile.encoding=UTF-8"
```

server.xml - In Connector tag for the GET (not really relevant for me) added "URIEncoding" attribute as

```
    <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
               connectionTimeout="20000" 
               redirectPort="8443" URIEncoding="UTF-8"/>
```

and uncommented the UTF-8 filter within the web.xml

```
    <filter>
        <filter-name>setCharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-
    class>org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            encoding</param-name>
            UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <async-supported>true</async-supported>
    </filter>
```

Now I'm out of ideas and hope for some helpful hints :)

thanks!

Edit: It seems that any UTF-8 Code > U+00A0 are not working correctly
snippet

```
U+00A1  ¡   c2 a1   INVERTED EXCLAMATION MARK
U+00A2  ¢   c2 a2   CENT SIGN
U+00A3  £   c2 a3   POUND SIGN
U+00A4  ¤   c2 a4   CURRENCY SIGN
...

Sysout: Â¡ Â¢ Ã£ Ã¤...
```

EDIT:

I've tried anything I've found but its still not working: System.properties() returns the following. Perhaps someone has another idea.

`logger.debug("SETTINGS: " + System.getProperties() );
     ...
     file.encoding.pkg=sun.io
     javax.servlet.request.encoding=UTF-8
     sun.jnu.encoding=ANSI_X3.4-1968
     file.encoding=UTF-8
     sun.io.unicode.encoding=UnicodeLittle
     ....`

Comment: First try `\u00A7` instead of `§`. This is to check whether the editor and the jspc compiler use the same encoding (WYSInWYG). Try this for both .java and .jsp. Somehow UTF-8 bytes where interpreted differently.

Comment: thanks for your anser: the jsp interpretes it correctly as § and the java(tomcat) part Java printing... \u00A7: Â§

Comment: Check the JSPs in the .war. For instance building with **maven**, using copying filtered resources might play havoc, especially with .properties that must be in ISO-8859-1.

Answer (score 0):

At the top of the jsp:

```
<%@page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"
%><!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
```

(I am afraid such is already the case.) Inspect in the browser the page encoding and the HTML source text.

Comment: This is  added already wihtin the code. the form data are interpreted correct and are submitted to the webserver correctly too. (wireshark trace)

Comment: My chaotic back and forth running would include trying an other browser, check caching tools, deployment and so on. But if `\u00A7` is mangled too, most likely some **web filter** might be guilty: a minifier or such. Also check the sources for `new String, getBytes, InputStreamReader, OutputStreamReader` without Charset. Sorry my answer did come seeing the "&lt" edit junk at 1. of the question.